# How to compare an array against a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

Suppose I have a list that contains a bunch of `numpy` ndarrays (or even `torch` Tensors):

```
a, b, c = np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)
collection = [a, b, c]
```

Now if I was to check whether array `b` was in `collection` (assuming I don't know what arrays exist in `collection`), then attempting: `b in collection` spits out the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

And the same would apply to tuples containing arrays.

One way around this was to do a list comprehension:

```
True in [(b == x).all() for x in collection]
```

However this requires a `for` loop and I was wondering if there was a more "efficient" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this was much simpler than anticipated...

You can literally just **stack** your arrays/tensors into a *higher* dimension (depth/channels in this case) and then the resultant is an array that is a collection of all the other arrays but stored independently in a "different dimension".

```
a, b, c = np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)
collection = np.stack((a, b, c))
```

Now you can simply check for `b` in `collection` as if you were comparing it against a list:

```
b in collection
> True
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use numpy arrays the whole way through:

```py
import numpy as np
a, b, c = np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)
array = np.dstack([a, b, c])
print(array.shape)
# (3, 3, 3)
np.all(array == b, axis=1).all(axis=1).any()
# True
```

Comment: very nice solution :)

Comment: @Paul H The final line was giving me False. Maybe np.stack() rather than np.dstack()?

Answer (score 1):

You can stack arbitrary shaped tensors along `axis=0` in a numpy array and then compare all remaining axes at once with `np.all` (this is just a slightly clearer version of PaulH's answer):

```
ugly_shaped_tensor_list = [np.random.rand(3,7,5,3) for j in range(10)]
known_tensor = ugly_shaped_tensor_list[1]

# stack all tensors in a single array along axis=0:
tensor_stack = np.stack(ugly_shaped_tensor_list)

# compare all axes except the "list" axis, 0:
matches = np.all(tensor_stack == known_tensor, axis=(1,2,3,4))
# array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
matches.any()
# True
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the keyword "axis" refers to exactly? Like if it was set to only 2, what would that mean, what exactly is it comparing?

Comment: think of them as labels for cartesian axes of a tensor.  For a matrix (nested arrays), axis 0 == row value , axis 1 == column value